# La url del método de mi controlador se aumenta cada vez que hago un click Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

Tengo problemas a la hora de hacer clicks en algún botón que llama al método de un controlador,
a veces la vista no carga porque primero llama al controlador/metodo y después a la vista, y la url queda en error, por ejemplo

Si estoy en esta url http://localhost/challenge-ci2/operationc y después hago click dentro de la vista en un botón, por ejemplo en un botón para realizar el update de una operacion, mi URL queda de esta forma, 
 http://localhost/challenge-ci2/operationc/operationc/update 
y si vuelvo a hacer click en update otra vez, la url se vuelve a alargar, quedando de esta forma, 
http://localhost/challenge-ci2/operationc/operationc/operationc/update 
 Estuve buscando  preguntas ya formuladas al respecto, pero no pude hallar una solución, dejo la forma en que llamo a la vista

```
 public function update(){
        $data['id'] = $this->input->post('mid');
        $data['amount'] = $this->input->post('mamount');
        $data['concept'] = $this->input->post('mconcept');        
        $data['categoryId'] = $this->input->post('mcategory');
        $data['type'] = $this->input->post('mtype'); 
        $data['personId'] = $this->session->userdata('id');      
        $this->operation->update($data);
        $this->loadOperation();  // LLamo a que se cargue la vista
}
    private function loadOperation($data = null){
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('name');
        $data['lastname'] =$this->session->userdata('lastname');
        $this->load->view('layouts/nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('operation/operationv');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }
```

Lo mismo me pasa si desde la vista cuando intento acceder a un controlador desde otro, por ejemplo,mi URL actual, http://localhost/challenge-ci2/loginc/login, quedaría así (loginc es el controlador y login es el método), dentro de esa vista, me carga la vista del controlador y en el NAV (mi navegación para cambiar de controladores), cuando doy click en el link que me lleva a un controlador llamado operationc (dejo el código), la url queda de esta forma http://localhost/challenge-ci2/loginc/operationc, dándome error al no encontrar el controlador en esa ruta, y cuando sólo funcionaría cuando la URL queda de esta forma, http://localhost/challenge-ci2/operationc

```
 <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php base_url()?>operationc">Operaciones</a>
    </li>
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiese explicar el por qué de esto con las URLs de codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

¿Configuraste base_url? Si es así puedes probar así: `<?php echo base_url().'operationc/update/' ;?>`

Comment: Sí, lo tengo configurado                         
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/challenge-ci2/'; 
Esa es mi URL, de hecho, si uso mucho el base_url y me funciona, pero hay casos en que no, como el que mencioné, que no me funciona correctamente (obviamente algo estoy haciendo mal para que no me funcione de esa forma)